# Laravel artisan migrate command not running on Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I recently just setup laravel homestead on my development machine and everything has been smooth and I love it. However, I am trying to add some columns to an existing table using migration but when running the `php artisan migrate` command doesn't complete. It seems to start but never completes even after leaving it for more than 10mins.

Here's my migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class AddColumnsToTransfersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('transfers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('otp')->after('bank_code')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('authorized')->after('otp')->nullable()->default('0');
            $table->string('recipient_code')->after('authorized')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('approval_required')->after('recipient_code')->nullable()->default('0');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('approved_by')->after('approval_required')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('approved_by')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('set null');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('transfers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the result of the command `php artisan migrate`
[image]

I know db connection is fine as I am able to login and pull data from the database inside the application. I was able to generate the migration file using `php artisan make:migration` command so I have no idea why is seems to be stuck when I try to run the actual migration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was an issue with mysql service. So I stopped the service by running `sudo service mysql restart` then ran `php artisan migrate`, and the table was successfully migrated. Problem solved.